# Does Hot Chocolate graphql-platform have CLI to auto generate resolver code based on Schema.graphql?

Tags: hotchocolate

Does Hot Chocolate graphql-platform have CLI to auto generate resolver code based on Schema.graphql what people commonly refers as `schema-first`

This is the closest answer I found to the question I have whether hot-chocolate support auto-generated code
https://github.com/ChilliCream/hotchocolate-docs/blob/master/docs/schema-first.md

But in this link, I could not find a clue about how to auto-generate code

Thanks!